# Post data from android to php

Tags: php, android, http-post

I have an android application that i using to post data to a website using http post but it is not posting any data to the website.

In my android code:

```
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude)));  
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude))); 
                   response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("url", postParameters);
```

In executeHttpPost method

```
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList postParameters)
        throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the php source

```
$lat=$_POST['latitude'];  
$long=$_POST['longitude'];  


mysql_connect('localhost','welcome','Welcome123') or die('conn error');
mysql_select_db('es')  or die('select error');

$query = "insert into GEO_LOC (GEO_LOC_LAT,GEO_LOC_LONG) values ($lat,$long)";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
echo 1;
}
else echo "Database Error";
?>
```

But this post method does not do anything . Am i missing something? Do i have to add anything additional?

Comment: define 'doesn't do anything'

Comment: There is no response or anything . The response returns null.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(ADD URL HERE);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> name = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        name.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude))); 
        name.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude)));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(name));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
} catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: your inputStreamReader is assuming the server uses the same encoding as your device.

Comment: Check inside executeHttpPost(). you are getting postParameters.

Answer (score 0):

check below code:

```
public static ArrayList<NameValuePair> arrayPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

add parameter in above array if array size is 0 then,

```
if (arrayPost.size() <= 0) {
                arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "test"));
            }
```

---

```
public static String Call_Http_URL_PostMethod(String url)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String is = null;
        try {

            if (arrayPost.size() <= 0) {
                arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "test"));
            }

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayPost, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
            is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("post responce----->", "" + is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("post responce error ----->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());
            is = null;
        }
        return is;
    }
```

change your php code like below(this is just for testing)

```
if($result)
{
echo json_encode("result"=array("sucsess"););
}

echo json_encode("result"=array("Database Error"));
```

Comment: Still same result .. The "is" is returning null

Comment: check my edited ans. fist run your url in browser it ll show you some data? if yes then this code ll working fine.

Comment: It is not sending any data to the webpage. The webpage is not getting called

Comment: if your using local server in your pc the use your ip address like : http://10.0.0.10/test/test.php you can also check this : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/connecting-mysql-database-in-android.html

Comment: No I am actually calling a web page that is hosted . Not local server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25199/discussion-between-sam-and-dhaval-sodha-parmar)