# HTTP post message with Java and PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I am new to PHP and Java http client, I am trying to post a message to my PHP script on my server, I tried  the following example: http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/11/15/android-tutorial-how-to-post-data-from-an-android-app-to-a-website/

However I am not able to understand how to send the JSON result back to my android app, following is the code I am using:

JAVA:

```
      public void send(View v)
      {
     // get the message from the message text box
     String msg = Et.getText().toString();  

     // make sure the fields are not empty
     if (msg.length()>0)
     {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://animsinc.com/query.php");
     try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);
       Et.setText(""); // clear text box
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }

     }
     else
     {
        // display message if text fields are empty
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

 }
```

PHP:

```
       <?php

       require 'phtry.php';

       $message = $_POST["message"]; 

       $query = "SELECT `surname`,`firstname` FROM `users`";


       $query1 = "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE id = $message";

      if ($query_run = mysql_query($query1)){
 //echo 'Success.';
 while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

$surname = $query_row['surname'];
$firstname = $query_row['firstname'];



}


$out [] = $query_row;
print(json_encode($out)); // If I check with my web browser I get a [false] display here

}else{
    echo 'No Success';
}


    ?>
```

As I am new to this, I want to know as well if I am doing things correct.

Comment: So what is not working? $_POST["message"] is empty?

Comment: First thing to do is remove echo $surname; 
echo $firstname;  This will cause the json to fail.

Comment: I don't know much about client side java code but if you want to POST info to a PHP and then retrieve the result this should be a AJAX call, and if that's what this is, where is the callback function? :S

Comment: Also, if you are using JOSN you need to use the JSONObject class in android. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578441/example-of-how-to-download-json-from-server

Comment: I had kept the post message empty to check if my query was working, sorry to remove the double slash.

Comment: Everything is working, I want to know how do I post this information I have fetched through PHP, back to my phone.

Comment: Your code is perfect you have to add just few lines in JAVA CODE just check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090616/1168654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess on the PHP side. You can't just echo things. This will cause the JSON parsing to fail.

I recommend you use the lightweight [GSON library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) from Google self. You use POJO classes to parse the json. Once you have a POJO class with GSON, all you have to do is use the `HttpResponse` from your `HttpPost` to read the response itself, like this:

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "asdf");
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));

            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);

            Response finishresponse = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
            return finishresponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

In my case, my POJO class is the `Response` class I created.